# ASP.NET Web API async controller method and deadlock

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, async-await, deadlock

Please help me to understand why this code cause a deadlock?
I have an asp.net web api application and I tried to make some controller method asynchronous.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authentication]
    public async Task<SomeDTO> PostSomething([FromBody] SomeDTO someDTO)
    {
        return await _service.DoSomething(someDTO);
    }
```

this is how looks the called service method:

```
    public async Task<SomeDTO> DoSomething(SomeDTO someDTO)
    {
...
        var someTask = Task.Run(() => 
        {
            var entity = new SomeEntity(someDTO);
            return _repository.Create(entity);
        });
...
        var result = await someTask;
...
    }
```

And there is some globalhandler, that prints a response to a console.

```
    public class AppGlobalHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var resp = base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            Debug.WriteLine($"Response:{request.RequestUri}{Environment.NewLine}{resp?.ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult()?.Content?.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult()}");
            return resp;
        }
    }
```

Looks like ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult()
blocks the caller thread, but I supposed that ConfigureAwait(false) should avoid this, isn't it?

Comment: Why do you wrap your code in a Task.Run()? It makes no sence to force sync code to run async, it will only use more threads. If you cant go async all the way, stick to sync.

Comment: this is a part of code, i need to run some operations parallel
@MarcusHöglund

Comment: I did not see where anything will run parallel in your code. Remember: async != parallel

Comment: "this is a part of code" means: little chance that we will spot the deadlock.

Comment: otoh, does it deadlock without that (and similar) `Debug.WriteLine()` lines?

Comment: @HenkHolterman no, without that line it is not.

Comment: there are some similar tasks that inserts or updates something

Comment: *but I supposed that ConfigureAwait(false) should avoid this, isn't it?* only if all awaiters would be configured ... but you have `await someTask`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ConfigureAwait(false) would not help you here because it must be all the way down in the call stack (see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45034554/how-to-correctly-block-on-async-code)) not at place where you wait synchronously, i.e. it depends rather on the implementation of base.SendAsync. If it acquired a lock on current thread it's too late to do something about it. It is also not recommended in ASP.net pipeline to continue responding on other thread after all (see discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489065/best-practice-to-call-configureawait-for-all-server-side-code) and post [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)).

Finally it is always a highly risky idea to wait synchronously in async context.
If you need to read content, why not doing it like that:

```
 public class AppGlobalHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var resp = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        var content = resp?.Content != null 
           ? (await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()) 
           : string.Empty; 
        Debug.WriteLine($"Response:{request.RequestUri}{Environment.NewLine}{content}");
        return resp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you overlook async keyword in Task.Run() method.

```
    public async Task<SomeDTO> DoSomething(SomeDTO someDTO)
    { 
        var someTask = Task.Run( async () => //simply add this for async run 
        {
            var entity = new SomeEntity(someDTO);
            return _repository.Create(entity);
        }); 
        var result = await someTask;
    }
```