# Call .Result on Async Method that has awaited results

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I have a class that returns a custom HttpClient that under the hood gets a token to use so the user doesn't have to personally get the token. I was just curious if I can call .Result on my async method that I already "awaited" for when returning the results in that method

```
public class CustomClient
{
   private static Int32 _refreshRate = 0;
   private static Sring _token;
   private static DateTime _tokenExpires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

   public static HttpClient Client
   {
       get { return GetNewClient(); }
   }

   private static HttpClient GetNewClient()
   {
      DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

      if (now > = _tokenExpires)
      {
         var tokenTask = GetTokenAndRefreshRate().Result; //Is this OK
         _token = tokenTask.Item1;
         _refreshRate = tokenTask.Item2;
         _tokenExpires = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(_refreshRate);
      }

      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_token))
      {
         throw new Exception("Cannot get access token");
      }

      HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
      clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };

      var httpClient = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
      httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _token);

     return httpClient;
   }

   private static async Task<Tuple<String, Int32>> GetTokenAndRefreshRate()
   {
      Task<String, Int32> tokenTask = Task.Run(() => 
      {
         Int32 refreshRate = 0;
         String token = TokenManager.CreateAuthorizationToken(out refreshRate);
         return new Tuple<String, Int32>(token, refreshRate);
      });

      var result = await tokenTask;
      return new Tuple<String, Int32>(result.Item1, result.Item2);
   }

}
```

Comment: `GetTokenAndRefreshRate()` returns as soon as the first `await` is hit, and that `Task` will not be complete, so no it isn't OK.

Comment: Also, [Don't Use Task.Run in the Implementation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html),

Comment: I was trying to avoid making the Client from being async if possible and only the call to get the token async. Any suggestions?

Comment: No suggestions? As I said, I don't want to make the method async and in your example that's exactly what it does.

Comment: You can create your own HTTP message handler and attach it to your HTTP client. The handler will be responsible for token management  such as: checking token expiration and attaching it to the Header.

Comment: Possibly related questions: [How to correctly block on async code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45034554/how-to-correctly-block-on-async-code) and also [An async/await example that causes a deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021304/an-async-await-example-that-causes-a-deadlock).

Comment: What does `CreateAuthorizationToken` do that you feel it needs to be made `async`? And why can't it be *real* async?

Comment: I don't want to block anybody else seeing how the token may need to be refreshed every 30 seconds. I think a refresh token is less expensive, but an authenticated token takes a bit of time to get. We are on a network where there could be many others getting tokens as well.

Comment: Liker so many others you've made the assumption that tasks are threads and that `Task.Run` magically makes your program multi-threaded. You are wrong.

Comment: @IanKemp the `Task.Run` invokes the action on a `ThreadPool` thread, so yes it makes a program multithreaded. There is nothing wrong in this assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Result` is a blocking call, which is bad on an async method.

Usually, when creating such wrapper classes, you have some state to it.
Since the only public member of your class is a property that effectively functions as a method, you can just use that instead, an async method. No need to call an async method in a property body if there is no property.

if you intended for the class to be a wrapper for the `HttpClient`, you should change the property to be initialized using a private constructor and create an async static method `CreateAsync()`. This method builds the `CustomClient` and can call async code using `await`.

EDIT:

Since your async method to get the token does not actually contain async code, you should just call it synchronously instead. Considering the fact that refresh time is in seconds, this call should not take long enough to justify forcing it to be async. If it is, thats a different problem.

Here is an example of how i would create this wrapper class:

Note that this is now a singleton wrapper instead of a pseudo-factory.
The Client can be accessed over a Singleton implementation `_instance` using `Client`

Note: `_minTokenLifetime` is required so you cant get an unrefreshed client with only half a second remaining. The minimum timespan is up to you. I used 20 in my example.

```cs
public class CustomClient
{
    private DateTime _tokenExpires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    private readonly TimeSpan _minTokenLifetime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);

    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    private static CustomClient? _instance;

    public static HttpClient Client => (_instance ??= new CustomClient()).GetRefreshedClient();

    protected CustomClient()
    {
        HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (_, _, _, _) => true
        };

        _client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
    }

    private HttpClient GetRefreshedClient()
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

        if (_tokenExpires - now < _minTokenLifetime)
        {
            string token = TokenManager.CreateAuthorizationToken(out int refreshRate);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                throw new Exception("Cannot get access token");
            }

            _tokenExpires = now.AddSeconds(refreshRate);
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        }

        return _client;
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is I want the user of this class to always have a current token (which expires often). So I can either create some kind of task scheduler to handle that or simply take the approach I did and that is every time the user "uses" the client, I see if they have a current token, if not I get one.

Comment: @JohnGrove What are you currently using the refreshRate for? Usually when you use access tokens like this, theres some kind of mechanism to determine if the token is expired/retrieve another one. You have something that looks a token refresh time limit implemented, why do you not use that?

Comment: @JohnGrove I have updated my answer to provide an example, this should fulfill your requirements

Answer (score -2):

So if I understand Jonathan's suggestions, it is to make the getting of the token a synchronous call but call it asynchronously. Then I would "wait" for the method "before" getting the result. If I understand him correctly I think he means to do this:

```
private static Tuple<String, Int32> GetTokenAndRefreshRate()
{
   Int32 refreshRate = 0;
   String token = TokenManager.CreatAuthorizationToken(out refreshrate);
   return new Tuple<String, Int32>(token, refreshRate);
}

//And then to call it in code
var tokenTask = Task.Run(() => GetTokenAndRefreshRate());
tokenTask.Wait();

var result = tokenTask.Result;
```

Comment: It's unclear how this answer solves the problem, mainly because it's unclear what the problem is.

Comment: You're right, maybe there is no problem. I was just asking if my approach was correct.  Johnathan mentioned a few things which I could do, which I thought I corrected and posted only to be downvoted for it (Unless I implemented it incorrectly).

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, I will definitely do that as I move forward.